# Print selected 2 different value in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME = 'JOHN' OR NAME ='JILL' AND SelectedDate > NOW ;
```

I'm trying to select 2 person name from my table column  and date bigger than today, somehow it success printed the result, but it will show the date lesser than today.

Answer (score 2):

Add brackets so you don't get all the JOHNs whose SelectedDate is in the past

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (NAME = 'JOHN' OR NAME ='JILL') AND SelectedDate > NOW ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are wrong.  But, use `IN` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE NAME IN ('JOHN', 'JILL') AND SelectedDate > NOW ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this below.  I'm not sure by what you said if you need greater than current date or less than current day.  Either way, just flip the < > to change it.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME In ('JOHN','JILL') AND SelectedDate > getdate() ;
```